# Is it possible to have a Single twitter APP authorisation to be used with multiple platforms?

Tags: authentication, twitter, web-applications

Is it possible to authenticate users with a twitter APP and use same authentication with multiple platform that uses the same APP ?

Ex. The twitter app DEMOAPP is used in 2 websites/platforms site1 and site2. Users grants authorisation to DEMOAPP at site1 but unaware of site2.

Is it possible for site2 to use the authorisation granted to DEMOAPP ?